# BeautifulSoup unable to find Div using ID

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape prices from Amazon and am using requests and BeautifulSoup4. The snippet from the script is as follows

```
headers = {
'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}

amazon_url = "https://www.amazon.com/gp/offer-listing/B076KDY7VF/ref=dp_olp_new_mbc?ie=UTF8&condition=new"

r = requests.get(url=amazon_url, headers=headers)
page_text = r.text

soup = BeautifulSoup(page_text, "html.parser")

# Finding the Price Table
table = soup.find(id="olpOfferListColumn")

print(table)
```

The table always outputs as **None**. I am not sure what the issue is. Please explain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `html.parser` doesn't recognize/treats unclosed tags as actual tags. If you execute `soup.div` you will see that it only takes one div tag. The only one that has a closing tag in the source code. If you use the `lxml` parser it will add the closing tags and your code will work.

```
headers = {
'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}

amazon_url = "https://www.amazon.com/gp/offer-listing/B076KDY7VF/ref=dp_olp_new_mbc?ie=UTF8&condition=new"

r = requests.get(url=amazon_url, headers=headers)
page_text = r.text

soup = BeautifulSoup(page_text, "lxml")

# Finding the Price Table
table = soup.find(id="olpOfferListColumn")

print(table)
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. This worked perfectly and I now understand why.